# Set custom immutablejs keys to prevent data duplication?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutability, immutable.js

I have data that comes in the following format as `action.places`.

I'd like to combine this only with new data coming in and return a new map of the updated places. If I get an object of places and one of the places has the same lat/lon as a previous place, I don't want to append that data.

```
{
  places: [
    {
      place: {
        lat: 123,
        lon: 321,
      }
    },
    {
      place: {
        lat: 432,
        lon: 234,
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

How would I do this with a map? Currently I'm appending this way but everything is duplicated, I can't find a non messy solution:

```
case RECEIVE_PLACES:
  return state
    .set('places', state.get('places').update(fromJS(action.places)))
```

Ideally I'd set the key of each obj to [`${lat},${lon}`] (only unique way to identify a place), that way I'd only have to iterate over the keys to get my places.

Comment: Based on this description I think that you should consider using a `Set` instead of a `List` for storing the "places".

Comment: I'm using a `Map`. @Josep - I updated the question.

Comment: Nope, you are not. At the top level you are, but "places" is a List, that's because `fromJS` by default converts an Array into a List.

Comment: Ah ok in that sense then yes - I'd LIKE to take each place and add it to a map using a combination of lat/lon as the key for each.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that if instead of using a `List` for storing the places you were using a `Set` you wouldn't have that issue because it wouldn't allow for duplicates to exist. There are 2 ways that you can accomplish that, by using the other parameters of the `fromJS` function so that it makes the transformation that you want or you do it manually. If you want I can give you that code in an answer. Are you interested or you don't want a Set? I mean, if the order of the items is not relevant to you, you should really use a Set :-)

Comment: @Josep Interesting! Yes I'd love to give that a looksie. The data doesn't need to be ordered, just unique.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130049/discussion-between-eveo-and-josep).

Answer (score 1):

you can filter out the repeated place items

```
case RECEIVE_PLACES:  {
  const newPlaces = fromJS(action.places).filter((newItem) => (
    !state.get('stores').find((oldItem) => (
      oldItem.place.lat === newItem.place.lat &&
      oldItem.place.lon === newItem.place.lon
    )
  );

  return state.set('stores', state.get('stores').update(newPlaces));
}
```

Comment: What about using the lat and lon as keys? This way seems a bit convoluted.

Comment: @eveo you can do that but u are changing the schema of the data and the solution i gave is no less in performance.

Comment: you gave me an identical solution as to my previous problem, I'm taking a different approach now, so obviously the schema will change.

Comment: its up to u if u want to change schema of objects u receive from api's. personally i feel its a bad practice because u have to undo ur schema changes to pass the object as a payload to ur other CRUD API's.

Comment: Ah I didn't mean response schema, I meant the format in which I'm massaging this data into new has changed since my last question, and on the client side it's trivial to rewrite it to use the new object 'schema' I'd like to form when receiving and combining new data with the old.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an Immutable.Set instead of a Immutable.List for persisting the places then everything would be easier and things would perform better.

So, if in your reducer you did something like:

```
import { Map, Set, fromJS } from 'immutable';

const initialState = new Map([
  ['places', new Set()],
  // Whatever other props that Map has
]);

const yourReducer = (state = initialState, { type, places }) => {
  switch (type) {
    RECEIVE_PLACES:
      return state.update('places', places => places.merge(
        new Set(fromJS(places))
      );
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

You should be fine.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I don't get `places => places.merge()`. I don't have access to 'places' like that, but action.places. Also in initialState, why wrap in square brackets? Why not `places: new Set()`. Also I'm returning state and setting other things in state, so it needs to be within a set call too.

Comment: In the code that I provided I de-structured the action, in the parameters, notice the end of this line `const yourReducer = (state = initialState, { type, places })` ? That's ES6 de-structuring.

If you have a look at the documentation of `Immutable.Map` you will notice that when initializing a new Map you should be passing an Array with tuples. Each tuple should have the key in the first position and the value in the second position.

Comment: Ah okay yes makes sense. I still don't get it. Do I do `action.places => action.places.merge(Set(fromJS(action.places)))` Whaaaaat?

Comment: No, no, no... The action should always have a plain javascript object, it's your state the one that is an Immutable. So if you don't do the destructuring then just do

`state.update('places', places => places.merge(Set(fromJS(action.places)))`.

Or perhaps: `state.update('places', places => places.merge(Set(fromJS(action.places.places)))`.

Depending on whether action.places looks like this: `{ places: [{
      place: {
        lat: 123,
        lon: 321,
      }
    }] }` or like this `[{
      place: {
        lat: 123,
        lon: 321,
      }
    }]`

Comment: So, if action.places is an Array do `state.update('places', places => places.merge(Set(fromJS(action.places)))` otherwise, if the array is in action.places.places, then do:`state.update('places', places => places.merge(Set(fromJS(action.places.places)))`

Comment: Hmm I got an error `Set: incorrect invocation` with `return state.set(..).set(..).update('places', places => places.merge(Set(fromJS(action.places))))`. action.places being `{ places: [ { place: { lat: 123, lon: 321, } }, { place: { lat: 432, lon: 234, } }, ] }`. I want to update my set with each new unique place object, of which I could receive 10, or 20, or just 1.

Comment: why are you doing state.set(..., you are supposed to do state.update('places', ...

Comment: I have to update the loading state and error state along with the places.

Comment: if I do new Set() instead of just Set, I get a "places.merge" is not a function error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130056/discussion-between-eveo-and-josep).